# Spring-cloud-contract: Stubrunner repository root: get credentials from maven settings

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

When using `AutoConfigureStubRunner`, I'd like to have the credentials for `repositoryRoot` stored in Maven's `settings.xml`, and specify only the repository URI (or alias) in the code.

Is there a way for Spring-Cloud-Contracts/`AutoConfigureStubRunner` to extract these credentials from Maven's settings?

I can provide the uri+credentials as an environment variable `STUBRUNNER_REPOSITORY_ROOT`, but I still need to explicitly set the credentials in it, and in my configuration I can't run arbitrary code to provide the value, so I can't extract the credentials from settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `stubrunner.server-id` to match the `id` in `settings.xml`. You can check for more options here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html#appendix

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Marcin's answer:

- Use `repositoryRoot` to specify the *URI* of the repository, without credentials. There might actually be support for multiple URIs here, comma-separated.
- Use `stubrunner.server-id` property to specify a `server` entry from `settings.xml` which has the relevant credentials. There's support for at-most one such value.
- Add this dependency to your project (otherwise you'll have some missing classes in run-time):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.sisu</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.sisu.plexus</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>
```